# Looking for Flutter Desktop Camera Plugin

Tags: linux, flutter, camera, desktop-application

I’m looking for Flutter Desktop Camera Plugin. I develop a Flutter desktop application that will use webcam on desktop under Ubuntu Linux. I can see the only mobile camera support in flutter. Can someone tell me if there are plugins for working with a webcam on a linux desktop?

Answer (score 0):

There is an **open issue** on this perhaps Linux support is near being stable this will be resolved soon.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41710